# Select non-null columns for each row in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe where the rows are different cases and the columns are possible events, in the form:

```py
df_prob
index  colA colB colC ColD
  0     NaN  0.9  NaN  0.1
  1     NaN  NaN  0.3  0.7
  2       1  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I need to build a df where each case is listed with the possible events for that case:

```py
df_order
index case event prob
  0    0    colB  0.9
  1    0    colD  0.7
  2    1    colC  0.3
  3    1    colD  0.7
  4    2    colA   1
```

The added difficulty is that it is a very scattered matrix so most of its values are NAN and I have been trying to find some method without using loops, as it is a df of 30000 x 30000 approx.

Comment: Try  with `df.stack().reset_index()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stack` and then reset the index:

```
(df.set_index('index')
   .stack()
   .reset_index()
   .set_axis(['case', 'event', 'prob'], axis=1, inplace=False))

   case event  prob
0     0  colB   0.9
1     0  ColD   0.1
2     1  colC   0.3
3     1  ColD   0.7
4     2  colA   1.0
```